# Ruby-FFI producing constants when wrapping functions starting with capital letter?

Tags: c, ruby, ffi

I am trying to wrap a C library with Ruby-FFI. However, the function names from the library start with capital letters. As a result, it seems as if ffi is trying to generate constants, and when you try access them at runtime from Ruby, you get an error saying

```
NameError: uninitialized constant (name of function)
```

Is there a way to alias function names so that in ruby you can access them as methods with lower case names as they ought to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait, it seems that an example is shown here: https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Windows-Examples

What they do here is the following:

```
attach_function :message_box, :MessageBoxW, [ :pointer, :buffer_in, :buffer_in, :int ], :int
```

So it seems that attach_function allows you to pass the alias as the first parameter, followed by the usual parameters. Tried this and it seems it works.